# ImageMagick - How do you convert files recursively in the shell?

Tags: linux, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

I have a folder tree of several subfolders within subfolders of BMP files I'd like to convert to JPG format, but I can't figure out a working command to get mogrify/imagemagick to go through every folder recursively.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to pass list of files would be probably by using backticks and recursive `find` command:

```
mogrify -format jpg `find . -name '*.bmp'`
```

Comment: You may want to replace the backticks with `$( ... )` (*so much cleaner, and can be nested*)  and slap some double quotes around it, in case the files have spaces in them.  `"$( find . -iname '*.bmp' )"`

Comment: Hm, I only got this error when I ran your command, the one with "$( find etc". Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/SUDGnSzr

Comment: And the command from Michal didn't work either. Here's it's output: https://pastebin.com/XqkFH6sv

Comment: Both commands are correct and work as they should.
I would suggest to check the ImageMagick package - remove it, update package lists, install fresh software - and check permissions to files/directories you want to convert.